# Is there a way to use a JS variable that stores data in a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a global variable, created in a JS file that stores the link to a certain image. This image is subject to change, while the project is running, which should trigger a reload. However, the links for my images are stored in a JSON file(something like this: `{"url": "files/assets/250186/1/image.png"},`). Basically, I would like to use this variable instead of hardcoding the link into the JSON file, so that the user can change the image through the app, and not by changing the JSON file itself. However, trying something like `{"url": variable},` does not work, with the JSON file not working correctly.

How would I proceed?

Comment: If you're asking how to update the json file, then that has to be done server side.

Comment: We need to see your code logic.

Comment: hard to tell what you are trying to do. If you have a json file, normally that would get loaded into a json variable which can be modified at any point. are you trying to change the variable? or the contents of the file?

Comment: The url to the image is contained in the variable. I should be able to change the location of the variable whenever I need to, and it should automatically reflect the new url in the JSON file.